# How to get the GROUPING and OVER(PARTITION) functions to work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So we're learning MySQL in a class currently, and there's a bunch of us that basically can't run these functions. The professor has used examples in class that run on his system (he's currently running version 8.0.19) yet do not run on ours. We get the error message "Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION ap.GROUPING does not exist" when we try to run this:

```
SELECT IF(GROUPING(invoice_date) = 1, 'Grand totals', invoice_date) AS invoice_date,
IF(GROUPING(payment_date) = 1, 'Invoice date totals', payment_date) AS payment_date,
SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_total,
SUM(invoice_total - credit_total - payment_total) AS balance_due
FROM invoices
WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '2018-07-24' AND '2018-07-31' GROUP BY invoice_date, payment_date WITH ROLLUP;
```

His only real solution to try was to make sure we are running the 64bit version (which I am), so I've been trying to read up on my own and still having some trouble. My only real hypothesis is that maybe it's the version of MySQL that I am running. I've tried to update MySQL to a new version following this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-upgrading.html#windows-upgrading-installer

But once I get to step 3 of "**Upgrading MySQL with MySQL Installer**", I get this message
[this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzdqw.png).

[image]

Figured I'd try here to see if anyone else has any ideas on how I can fix this, or how I can actually upgrade to a newer version. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

[Here's the connection I use to get on MySQL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2ZSr.png) Always use the right one.

[image]

Comment: what does `select version();` report in the version you are running?

Comment: are you somehow connecting to some other server than the 8.0.23 you have installed?

Comment: @ysth It is 5.7.31. Sorry, I thought I said that in my post but looks like I forgot. That's what confused me too. When I go to my server status, it is on this version, but when I went to the upgrade screen, it said 8.0.23. Also, we are using wampserver. He also told us to make sure that it is the 64bit version, which it is.

Comment: When you open MySQL Workbench, are you connecting to the MySQL Server instance on localhost/127.0.0.1? Are you connecting to port 3306 (the default)? It's possible there's more than one instance running on your computer.

Comment: And for the record, the fact that you are connecting to a 5.7.31 instance definitely explains why the function is not found. As with all software, each new version introduces new features. You can compare the reference lists of [functions in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-function-reference.html) versus [functions in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-function-reference.html). GROUPING() and OVER() are features new in 8.0.

Comment: @BillKarwin I believe so. To make sure, I attached a screenshot of which one I use to get on MySQL. It's the blacked out one. We were told to just make our own connection. We weren't really told the ins and outs. Sorry I don't have more info. Any info on how I can connect to the 8.0.23 version it says I have installed?

Comment: That certainly looks like it's a configuration to connect to localhost. But if it's connecting to 5.7.31, then obviously there's another instance. You'd have to figure out where that instance is. I'd try [SERVICES.MSC](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-windows-services) to examine which MySQL Server service is running, and where it is. But my knowledge of Windows is dated — I have made an effort to avoid using it for years.